# light-weight recurring billing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment, recurring-billing

I've looked so far at ActiveMerchant and SAAS railskit. ActiveMerchant supports many gateways, but not all (like Google Checkout). Is there a library that supports just billing/recurring  reminders? That way I could use individual plugins for payment processors that I care about and control the "recurring" part through an abstract library.

UPDATE: This is about code, not a full SaaS solution, as it's just more vendor lock-in where I won't be able to provide all payment processors to the customer (CC, Paypal, Google Checkout).

Comment: You can use recurly.com.

Answer (score 2):

checkout braintree they are supporting recurring billing and reminders for every transaction   http://www.braintreepayments.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources:

- [Stripe](http://stripe.com) ([Railscast about it](http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe))
- Railscasts: "[PayPal Recurring Billing](http://railscasts.com/episodes/289-paypal-recurring-billing)" (need pro subscription)